# Tools to analyze files from DataWriter

Tags: redhawksdr

Are there any tools which I can use to open and look at the signal data which DataWriter writes to a file?  Ideally I'd like to grab a small subset of that signal and then just replay it using the DataReader Component.  Also if you know of any good sources of information about REDHAWK besides the official documentation that would be awesome(even general SDR resources).
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the format as described in the .sri file to identify data element boundaries, you can use the linux hexdump command to splice out sections of the data file.

The [NextMidas](http://nextmidas.techma.com/) project, part of which is embedded in the REDAWK IDE, can be used as a stand-alone tool in conjunction with the REDHAWK IDE to provide some data analysis capabilities.

NextMidas works with Midas Blue Files. To save your data in Blue File format, play the file written by DataWriter using DataReader. Right-click the output port of DataReader and select "Snapshot". In the wizard dialog, specify your desired parameters, including "Midas Blue File" as the file type. After saving the Blue File, you can use DATALIST and other NextMidas commands to analyze it.

You can also select any of several "Plot xxx" right-click options on the Data Reader output port, and plot the data using the IDE. There are some analysis capabilities inherent in the plot display.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read data written by DataWriter with DataReader.  That being said, you would need to have the correct endian settings.  For more information, the code for the DataWriter and DataReader components are available at the GitHub site for REDHAWK (https://github.com/redhawksdr), along with a number of other components, etc.

It should also be fairly simple to read data written by DataWriter into MATLAB/Octave after looking at the Python code for how the data is written.

As for general SDR, GNURadio is a similar framework for software-defined radio.  There are also videos on YouTube for creating REDHAWK waveforms, including some that use inexpensive hardware.

Comment: So as far as you know there aren't any tools already out there for analyzing the data written by DataWriter?

Comment: What do you mean by analyze?  The files written by DataWriter will be raw binary files consisting of little endian floats and an sri file that tells the DataReader how to interpret it (sample rate, complex/real, etc).  This data can be anything from complex baseband data straight from a device to the output of a BPSK demod.  Any analysis performed will be pretty application specific

Comment: Turns out I was looking for something like Baudline.